# I can't make a google maps marker

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have got my Coordinates from my Database, the problem is that, I can not add a marker with data.

If I put the coordinates manually then it works fine without any problems, but if I get the coordinates value from my Database, google maps, it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
var latitud = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $dbLatitud) . '"]' ?>;
var longitud = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $dbLongitud) . '"]' ?>;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = latitud + longitud;
 // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits[1];   --- especifico slot 
var a = latitud.toString();
var b = longitud.toString();
var myLatLong = {lat: a, lng: b};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLong,
  map: map,
  title: 'Colectivo N°: 1'
});

 marker.setMap(map);

}
```

I think the problem is with data types. Type of the database coordinates are in double, but I can't make a marker with other type data neither.

Comment: Please post the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it!

I changed .toString()

```
function myFunction() {
var latitud = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $dbLatitud) . '"]' ?>;
var longitud = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $dbLongitud) . '"]' ?>;
var a = latitud.toString();
var b = longitud.toString();
var myLatLong = {lat: a, lng: b};
}
```

with parseFloat();

```
function myFunction() {
var latitud = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $dbLatitud) . '"]' ?>;
var longitud = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $dbLongitud) . '"]' ?>;
var a = parseFloat(latitud);
var b = parseFloat(longitud);
var myLatLong = {lat: a, lng: b};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More simply don't cast the values as strings to begin with -- in other words remove the double quotes.

You can use `<?=` and `?>` as short hand to echo php variable without writing `echo`.

I haven't tested my assertion, but the documentation seems to suggest that you can't simply implode multiple values into `myLatLong`.  Do you actually only have one value for lat and long?  If so, this will do:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat:<?=$dbLatitud[0]);?>, lng:<?=$dbLongitud[0];?>},
  map: map,
  title: 'Colectivo N°: 1'
});
```

Furthermore, you could prep your data for direct insertion into the javascript using an associated array and `json_encode()`:

```
<?php
$lats=['lat'=>-33.890542];
$lng=['lng'=>151.274856];
?>
...
position: <?=json_encode($lats+$lng);?>
```

If you do have multiple markers, then [see this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) which uses a multidimensional array of data and uses a loop to apply all of the markers.  In which case, you again can/should use `json_encode()` in your php to prepare/format your database values for javascript.